# Correlation matrix of Gaussian copula

Tags: correlation, gaussian, copula

The question is related to the Gaussian copula.

Let $\Phi(x)$ denote the cdf of standard Normal distribution. Let $(X_1, X_2) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ be joint Normal with covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho \\ 
\rho & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I wonder, does $\mathbb{E}\Big[\Phi(X_1)\Phi(X_2)\Big]$ has an analytical expression? I tried by myself but the integration looks very messy.

Comment: I use Mathematica to test, but it gives no analytical solution. Then, I doubt there exists analytical solution.

Comment: @NN2 Thanks a ton! I won't have much hope then...